# Passport.js .authenticate() throwing TypeError: undefined is not a function

Tags: node.js, express, passport.js

I'm new to passport (and node in general) and have been using this tutorial (http://mherman.org/blog/2015/01/31/local-authentication-with-passport-and-express-4/#.VczPbTBViko) to add passport authentication to a larger web app. I think I have been following things correctly, but when I start the app in terminal, I get the following error.

```
passport.use(new LocalStrategy(Admin.authenticate()));
                                     ^
TypeError: undefined is not a function
    at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/goldru/design-data/app.js:37:38)
    at Module._compile (module.js:460:26)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:478:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:355:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:310:12)
    at Module.require (module.js:365:17)
    at require (module.js:384:17)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/goldru/design-data/bin/www:7:11)
    at Module._compile (module.js:460:26)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:478:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:355:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:310:12)
    at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:501:10)
    at startup (node.js:129:16)
    at node.js:814:3
```

I checked package.json and all of the relevant libraries appear to be installed.

Here is the relevant code.

from app.js:

```
//connect to db; require models
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost/design-data-test');
var Test = require('./models/Tests');
var Question = require('./models/Question');
var User = require('./models/User');
var Option = require('./models/Option');
var Admin = require('./models/Admin');

//require passport
var passport = require('passport');
var LocalStrategy = require('passport-local').Strategy;

var routes = require('./routes/index');

var express = require('express');
var app = express();

app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use(bodyParser.json());

//passport setup
app.use(passport.initialize());
app.use(passport.session());
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));

app.use('/', routes);

//config admin
var Admin = require('./models/Admin');
passport.use(new LocalStrategy(Admin.authenticate()));
passport.serializeUser(Admin.serializeUser());
passport.deserializeUser(Admin.deserializeUser());
```

admin.js:

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var passportLocalMongoose = require('passport-local-mongoose')

var AdminSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    username: String,
    password: String
});

AdminSchema.plugin(passportLocalMongoose);

module.export = mongoose.model('Admin', AdminSchema);
```

Comment: Can edit your questions and show parts of Admin, especially the definitions of authenticate, serializeUser and deserializeUser?

Comment: Admin is a mongoose model--the tutorial i was using didn't specify adding those functions to it. I think they are passport functions

Comment: They are most likely functions added by the plugin. Seeing it now, I guess your problem is a typo.

Comment: Did that change work?

Comment: Removing the empty parens? No

Comment: No. Replacing `module.export` with `module.exports`. As suggested in my edited answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a typo. You have to use `module.exports` and not `module.export` in admin.js.

Comment: it's a callback, so doesn't it need to be a function?

Comment: Yes it should be a function. But you should not call it inside app.js. Only specify its name.

Comment: hmm... I get the following error when I remove the empty parens

Comment: throw new TypeError('LocalStrategy requires a verify callback

Comment: Are you using the  `passport-local-mongoose` as suggested in the tutorial? Posting the contents of `models/Admin` here would help, too.

Comment: Yes, I am using passport-local-mongoose. Just made edit

Comment: I changed my answer, as I guess it is only a typo. Can you confirm this?