# "TypeError: passport.serialize is not a function" with Passport.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, passport.js, passport-local

I am relatively new to `passport.js` and have been following an online guide in conjunction with the documentation here: https://github.com/saintedlama/passport-local-mongoose. However, when I start my server in webstorm, I consistently get the error: `TypeError: passport.serialize is not a function.` I also saw this similar post: [Passport.js .authenticate() throwing TypeError: undefined is not a function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31995224/passport-js-authenticate-throwing-typeerror-undefined-is-not-a-function), but my problem is different from the one solved in that question. My relevant code is below:

> **user.js**

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose'),
Schema = mongoose.Schema,
passportLocalMongoose = require('passport-local-mongoose');
var User = new Schema({
    username: String,
    password: String,
    studentID: String,
    grades: [{
        subject: String,
        grade: String
    }]
});
User.plugin(passportLocalMongoose);
module.exports = mongoose.model('User', User);
```

> **app.js**

```
var express = require('express');
var path = require('path');
var logger = require('morgan');
var cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var routes = require('./routes/index');
var LocalStrategy = require('passport-local').Strategy;
var passport = require('passport');
var request = require('request');
var cheerio = require('cheerio');
var User = require('./models/user');

var app = express();
passport.initialize();
app.use(passport.initialize());
app.use(passport.session());
passport.use(new LocalStrategy(User.authenticate()));
passport.serialize(User.serializeUser());
passport.deserializeUser(User.deserializeUser());
```

All help is appreciated!

Comment: Instead of passport.serialize() do passport.serializeUser(User.serializeUser()); in the app.js. I looked at the documentation. I believe that might be your problem. I hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

There is no *passport.serialize* function. The correct is *passport.serializeUser*.

This is a code snipped from passport.

```
Authenticator.prototype.serializeUser = function(fn, req, done) {
...
```

and

```
Authenticator.prototype.deserializeUser = function(fn, req, done) {
...
```

I believe it is your problem.

Hope it can help.